# Use Observable to await for event to execute

Tags: c#, asynchronous, system.reactive

I'm trying to create an observable that listens for an event to be raised and allows me to await when it's executed. What I have so far looks like this:

```
    private async Task ConnectStatusMonitor()
    {
        // show the splash text
        SetSplashText("Connecting Server Status Monitor");

        var currentStatusChangedObservable = Observable.FromEventPattern(
            h => StatusManager.Instance.CurrentStatusChanged += h,
            h => StatusManager.Instance.CurrentStatusChanged -= h)
            .Take(1);

        using (currentStatusChangedObservable.Subscribe(ep => Console.WriteLine("On Next Triggered")))
        {
            await StatusMonitor.Instance.Start();

            // show the splash text
            SetSplashText("Waiting For Server Status");

            // execution awaits forever
            await currentStatusChangedObservable;
        }
    }
```

My `StatusManager` raises `CurrentSatusChanged` shortly after the call to `Start()`. I see "On Next Triggered" in my output, but it gets stuck on the last await.

I thought `Take(1)` would allow the Observable to know it was completed when the event had been raised once, and that awaiting on the observable would continue once the observable was completed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a classic asynchrony problem, you need to monitor for completion of any asynchronous activity before you start it. You could do this like this:

Before your first await put

```
var statusChanged = currentStatusChangedObservable.ToTask();
```

And then replace second await with

```
await statusChanged;
```

In your code as written, the final await is actually creating a second subscription to the event, which may have already fired.

Comment: Wasn't able to find a ToTask method, but RunAsync, which returns an AsyncSubject, seems to have done the trick. Thanks for pointing me in the right direction.

Comment: Good stuff! You need a using declaration for `System.Reactive.Threading.Tasks` to see `ToTask` - it's an extension method on `IObservable<T>` defined in `System.Reactive.Threading.Tasks.TaskObservableExtensions` in the `System.Reactive.Linq` assembly.

Answer (score 0):

A Clue: what if `CurrentStatusChanged` fires before you await it?

Comment: You're right, that's exactly what's happening. Now I'm trying to figure what I could do about that. Sometimes calling start will fire the event right away, other times it may be fired after a few seconds. I can't change when the event is fired, and I still want to await until the event is raised.